# What is the proper way to inject my own custom dependencies on an ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I have an architecture in which all the default dependencies are automatically injected through the `Initialize` and `OnActionExecuting`. This all works like a charm because, in runtime (not tests), the default controller activator will call these methods passing in the correct concrete objects. Fine.

My problem begins when I have a custom dependency not injectable in the `Initialize` and `OnActionExecuting` methods.

Exemple:

```
public class MyController
{
    private IEmailSender emailSender = null;
}
```

Well.. in runtime `emailSender` will be null unless I set it to something else. In this case I would end up with something not so great, like this:

```
public class MyController
{
    private IEmailSender emailSender = null;
    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
         if(this.emailSender == null)
              this.emailSender = new SomeConcreteEmailSender();
    }
}
```

Ugly. I don't want to do this "if null, instantiate" thing.

A more sofisticated way to inject `IEmailSender` would be creating my own `ControllerActivator` that would only be called in runtime (not tests) and would inject `IEmailSender` automatically without the need to do this "if". But I don't want to create a custom `ControllerActivator` for each controller that needs injection.

That being said, what is considered standard when it comes to custom dependency injection for ASP.NET controllers?

Comment: "what is considered standard when it comes to custom" - perhaps you could look at using a standard dependency injection framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That being said, what is considered standard when it comes to custom
>   dependency injection for ASP.NET controllers?

Constructor injection:

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public MyController(IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }

    ... actions using the _emailSender here ...
}
```

And here's what's considered as a *poor-man's-dependency-injection* (please do not use) for people that do not wish to use an existing dependency injection framework (because for example they work in a company where some technically illiterate morons dictate what frameworks should be used and what not) or are too lazy to write a custom dependency resolver:

```
public class MyController: Controller
{
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public MyController(): this(new SomeConcreteEmailSender())
    {
    }

    public MyController(IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }

    ... actions using the _emailSender here ...
}
```

Comment: The default ControllerActivator will not call my custom contructor and that would not let me dispose the "if" that I want

Comment: That's why you could write a custom one. Or if you don't want to reinvent the wheels you could use an existing dependency injection framework. Ninject is pretty nifty for example. All you have to do is install the `Ninject.MVC3` NuGet package, and then register your dependencies in the `AppStart` folder that was created for you. Ninject will register a custom [dependency resolver](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/service-location-pt5-idependencyresolver.html) for you so that you could inject dependencies in many places of your application such as controllers.

Comment: Yeah, it's quite nice. But the choice is really yours. There are so many existing dependency injection frameworks. Just pick one and start playing with it. But as far as the design of your dependencies into the controllers is concerned there's no doubt -> constructor injection. It allows for weaker coupling and easier unit testing of the different layers of your application in isolation.

Comment: @AndréPena: You can use Ninject, StructureMap, Autofac, Castle Windsor, Simple Injector, just pick one.